# Redis caches - when can large evictions be triggered?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

We have a Redis Cache on Azure `Standard 2.5gb`.  We observe the following behaviour:

[image]

Every now and then, we observe large drops in memory usage.  It appears that lots of resources are being evicted.

Things to note:

- Eviction policy is LRU
- Available cache size is 2.5gb
- No application code that would evict such large amounts of memory (largest objects are ~80kb and most are significantly smaller)
- Observed memory drops represent tens of thousands of keys
- We seldom use explicit expiry dates on cached objects, and when we do they are always < 1 hour.

My question is, apart from application logic explicitly evicting keys are there any other circumstances Redis would evict large amounts of keys?

Comment: Never used Redis Azure, but this doc has a tip about eviction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-configure#memory-policies

Comment: Is there any chance your evictions coincided with Azure Redis maintenance intervals?  If a shard went offline and was allowed to lose data, that might be one explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The memory cleanup may not represent evictions.**

You say "it appears" that lots of resources are being evicted, but if you are just relying on the reclaimed memory for that appearance, you may be chasing ghosts. Have you checked how this graph overlays with the `Total Keys` metric available in the Azure Portal? Overlaying the two series should allow you to see whether or not the memory reclamation *really* is due to eviction or if it's due to another process like Azure perhaps calling [MEMORY PURGE](https://redis.io/commands/memory-purge) periodically on the cache instance to clean up dirty pages?

Comment: You're right, total keys is continually growing (as I would expect) and there are no drops there.  I can't seem to find any other charts that correlate to the drops in memory usage.

Comment: Been giving this a lot more thought - we used Redlock.net for distributed locking which creates a lot of lightweight objects in the Redis cache.  Could this be what's causing the memory drops if this memory is being purged?

Comment: @TomGullen - I'm not familiar specifically with Redlock.net, but the couple of redis D-locking implementations I've seen do tend to produce a lot of key churn, so it does makes a lot of sense that the creation & subsequent deletion of distributed lock tracking keys would cause a lot of allocation & release of memory which should then, yes, be eligible to be reclaimed by MEMORY PURGE.

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems to be a reasonable explanation so will mark as correct answer.  I guess this could easily be tested by moving the locking to a different Redis cache.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your redis eviction policy to `noeviction` and see if that addresses your problem?  Doing so means you will have to manage all content yourself.  https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache has more details.

Comment: Not comfortable doing this in production, don't think this is an option.